# Sinon useFakeTimers() creates a timeout in before/afterEach

Tags: mocha.js, sinon

I'm using Sinon with Mocha to test some expiration date values. I used the same code a few months ago and it worked fine, but somewhere between v1.12.x and v1.17.x, something has changed and I can't seem to find the right path.

```
let sinon = require('sinon');
describe('USER & AUTHENTICATION ENDPOINTS', function(done) {
    beforeEach(function() {
        this.clock = sinon.useFakeTimers(new Date().getTime());
        return fixtures.load(data);
    });
    afterEach(function() {
        this.clock.restore();
        return fixtures.clear(data);
    });

    context('POST /users', function() { ... }
});
```

- I've tried with and without the `new Date().getTime()` argument.
- I've tried passing in and explicitly calling `done()`.
- I've tried removing my fixture load/clear processes.

The end result is always the same:

```
Error: timeout of 5000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

Has something changed that I just haven't noticed in the documentation? Do I have some kind of error in there that I can't see?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

So a little more info here. This clearly has something to do with my code, but I'm at a loss.

If I comment every actual test, the tests run and give me a green "0 passing".

If I run an actual test, even one that just this:

```
context('POST /users', function() {
    it('should create a new user', function(done) {
        done();
    })
});
```

I'm right back to the timeout. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mystery solved](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1267). It appears to be a conflict between Sinon and versions of Knex > 0.7.6.

> Seems to be because `pool2` relies on behavior of `setTimeout`. Using `sinon.useFakeTimers(...)` replaces several methods including `setTimeout` with synchronous versions which breaks it. Can fix by replacing with: `clock = sinon.useFakeTimers(Number(date), 'Date')`;

My original code was written in a world where Knex v0.7.6 was the latest version. Now that it's not everything failed even though the code itself was the same. I used the fix mentioned and things look to be fine.

Comment: You can use shouldAdvanceTime option, or clock.runAll() to resolve the issue, also if you want to use faketimers to mock, setTimeout, etc. in addition to just date.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `done` to your `describe` callback in line 2:

```
describe('USER & AUTHENTICATION ENDPOINTS', function(done) {
```

Mocha expects you to invoke it... To get rid of the timeout error, just remove the `done` parameter from the callback.

Comment: Yep, that was at least part of the problem, but doesn't appear to be all of the problem. Having removed it, I still see the same issue.

Comment: I ran your test myself with sinon 1.17.3, and I commented out your fixtures.load() and fixtures.clear() lines. For me the test is green without any timeouts. So maybe something weird is going on in these lines?

Comment: (And, to be honest, the test even is green with the "done" parameter in the outermost describe...)

Comment: Weird. If I remove the fixtures stuff and put the clock bits back in, I still get the same problem. With fixtures only, all green. This is really odd. I obviously have something sideways, but I surely can't seem to see it.

Comment: Hm... What if you start off with a completely new test file and add the bits one after one? When does the timeout occur the first time?

Comment: I had hoped to avoid that because ugh, but here we are. Seems to be the combo of the sinon + fixtures lines. The clock lines work fine if I comment the fixtures and the fixtures work fine if I comment the clock lines. Added a gist if you have a moment to take a look: https://gist.github.com/robwilkerson/d62262090f3ce2fa4fe666d4d95ebadc